# Does Cloud Kit allow multiple users to edit the same data, and can users be modified when data is edited?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I am thinking of using Cloud Kit in an app I am working on. I need to know if it has these two capabilities:

1. Multiple users can edit the same data stored in cloud kit, but only if they are authorized to.
2. If other users authorized to edit that data can be notified when the data is changed.

I can't seem to find an answer and don't want to get too far into integrating Cloud Kit if it isn't able to fulfill these requirements.

Comment: As rmaddy says, yes; although I would add a cautionary note; be careful with data volumes, the allowances on cloud kit are limited; the quota for the public database linked not to the users but the app itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both are supported.

1. You need to use the public database.
2. You need to use subscriptions to get notified.

All of this is covered in the [CloudKit Quick Start](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987).

Comment: This is now possible in the private database with `CKShare`, which didn't exist when this answer was posted.